# Do PVC glue, cement leave traces?

Tags: plumbing, drain, pvc, cpvc

Before a month, I bought a domestic air conditioner for my bedroom and the person who came to install it, used somewhere PVC glue with that strong toxic smell (you can smell glue without to have to turn on the air condition).

I don't know if they generally use that glue to install an air condition.

The smell stayed for days and the air condition was also periodically on (not for very long, only 10 hours in total because there was a glue smell in the air).

Now that smell left and I was wondering if it's safe to turn on the air condition and sleep or there are any toxic remainders (in the air) ?

Answer (score 1):

It was the glue outgassing a normal part of the process, the pvc was probably for a condensate drain (normal).  If you would left it running it may have out gassed faster but yes it is safe to use now.

Comment: The pipe is indoor (in built), I thought that the water doesn't go out with pressure so maybe it wasn't necessary for him to use the glue.

Comment: Water will leak if you don't glue it. Particularly from joints at the ends of horizontal-ish segments (even if sloped).

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere After a few days, water leaked in the room. Another person came and pulled out the pipe (very easy)  and blew inside. Isn't supposed that glue to be strong? He didn't used any glue after that